# How to un-delete cells in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, undo, recovery

Can it be done?

"Undo" only seems to work for blocks/lines of code *within* a cell

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

`Edit` > `Undo Cell Operation` (or using the shortcut `Z` in the command mode - to access the command mode press `ESC`)

or

`Edit` > `Undo` (or using the shortcut `CTRL`+`Z`)

[image]

---

**Option 2**

Alternatively, if one didn't restart the kernel, one can export the IPython history by running

```
%history -g   # If one wants to give a name to the file add "-f NAME"
```

Or access the content of all cells (including deleted ones) with `_ih` such as

```
_ih[-10:]
```

---

**Option 3**

If one already restarted the kernel, `File` > `Revert Notebook to Checkpoint`

[image]

Checkpoints will be stored in `.ipynb_checkpoints` so one can look inside the files and see if the deleted cell is there.

Comment: cheers! First one seems obvious in hindsight.  Thank-you for pointing it out.